# src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:95:20: Fatal error:Python.h error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, pip

In my CentOS 7.7, I installed python3 `yum install python3` and I want to install the `gevent` by pip3, but get below error:

```
    src/gevent/libev/corecext.c:95:20: Fatal error:Python.h：there is no that directory or file
     #include "Python.h"
                        ^
    Compilation interrupt
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-9sbqi31b/gevent/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-zgsgc2dj-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-9sbqi31b/gevent/
```

I found google, let me install the `python-dev`, but after I installed it, there still exist this error.

---

Update:
My pip3 version is `9.0.3`.

```
# pip3 --version
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Comment: What's the version of your pip?

Comment: `sudo yum install python3-devel`

Answer (score 2):

your pip version is low, you should update it.

by command:

```
sudo pip3 install pip --upgrade
```

Comment: Updating pip and python dev package fixed my issue.   sudo pip3 install pip --upgrade &&  sudo yum install python3.x-level